# post filter based on sum aggregation results in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

Currently I've got a query that aggregates values with a sum, I'd like to remove any buckets that don't hit a certain sum limit:

For example, summing a "distance" field, I'd like to only return results where the summed distance is within a specified range.

I thought this may be possible with a post_filter, but this seems a slightly different use case. For what it's worth, currently running 1.7 (this may be a limiter as I believe processing aggs is hard below 2.x)

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can support your question with mappings and queries you have tried so far